# Error inflating class fragment in Google Map

Tags: android, android-fragments

I just learned Android and I have some problems when I run the Google Map code.
I've tried lots of solutions in stack overflow:

1. Mainactivity.java: extends FragmentActivity instead of Activity
2. activity_main.xml: change the name of fragment to "com.samplefragsapplication.SuggestionFrags" or "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

and it still not work.

this is the activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

this is the Mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.asg2b;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

this is the Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.asg2b"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.asg2b.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" >
    </permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.asg2b.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.asg2b.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="Android Key" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is the log I got from LogCat

```
12-01 14:48:08.705: D/dalvikvm(14191): GC_CONCURRENT freed 312K, 4% free 12919K/13447K, paused 4ms+3ms
12-01 14:48:08.870: D/dalvikvm(14191): GC_CONCURRENT freed 306K, 5% free 13073K/13639K, paused 1ms+7ms
12-01 14:48:09.055: D/dalvikvm(14191): GC_CONCURRENT freed 360K, 5% free 13179K/13767K, paused 3ms+6ms
12-01 14:48:09.090: D/AndroidRuntime(14191): Shutting down VM
12-01 14:48:09.090: W/dalvikvm(14191): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c681f8)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.asg2b/com.example.asg2b.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:280)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1892)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at com.example.asg2b.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4562)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at com.lbe.security.service.core.client.b.x.callActivityOnCreate(Unknown Source)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    ... 11 more
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.cE(Unknown Source)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4339)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
12-01 14:48:09.110: E/AndroidRuntime(14191):    ... 21 more
12-01 14:48:18.250: D/dalvikvm(14191): GC_CONCURRENT freed 516K, 6% free 13130K/13895K, paused 5ms+4ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this in manifiest under **application tag**

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="4030500" />
```

EDIT:

and replace your activity_main.xml code by this code

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
         />
```

Comment: oh, I just had dinner before. The meta-data is in the application tag. just at the bottom of the tag. For you edit about activity_main.xml, it's still not working for the same err message.

Comment: I finally solve it! It's because the version of my mobile's play service is too low. And I also need to add the meta-data tag you mentioned. Thank you! @Hardik